# Magento 2.4.3-p2 Custom Module stopped sending emails

Tags: magento2, email, custom

My custom module used to send emails until one of the latest Magento Version upgrades.
I have no clue why it stopped sending them.

sendmail

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Schott\B2bCustomerSageCrm\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $transportBuilder;
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @var StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param StateInterface $state
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        StateInterface $state
    )
    {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $state;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function sendEmail(
        $id,
        $email,
        $customerFirstName,
        $customerLastName,
        $companyName
    )
    {
        $templateId = 'customer_crm'; // template id
        $fromEmail = 'no-reply@example.com';  // sender Email id
        $fromName = 'Frontname Text';             // sender Name
        $toEmail = 'example@icloud.com'; // receiver email id

        try {
            // template variables pass here
            $templateVars = [
                'customerid' => $id,
                'customeremail' => $email,
                'customerFirstName' => $customerFirstName,
                'customerLastName' => $customerLastName,
                'companyName' => $companyName
            ];

            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

            $from = ['email' => $fromEmail, 'name' => $fromName];
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();

            $storeScope = ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $templateOptions = [
                'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => $storeId
            ];
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId, $storeScope)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFromByScope($from)
                ->addTo($toEmail)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

email template

```
<!--@subject {{var companyName}} {{trans "=> Sage CRM success"}}  @-->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
            <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{trans "New customer registration to be confirmed in Sage CRM"}} </h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                    {{trans "CustomerId:"}} {{var customerid}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                    {{trans "CustomerMail:"}} {{var customeremail}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                    {{trans "CompanyName:"}} {{var companyName}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                    {{trans "CustomerName:"}} {{var customerFirstName}} {{var customerLastName}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA;text-align:center;">
                        <center>
                            <p style="font-size:12px;margin:0;">

                            </p>
                        </center>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the log files I do not see anything. Can somebody see a problem why I would not work with my current Magento version?

Answer (score 1):

The code is actually working, the problem was the sender's email address domain which was not in SendGrid.